# NiFi JOLT copy all original JSON

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm using Apache NiFi and I get some JSON as input. I want to create a new JSON, as follows:

```
{
     "data": ORIGINAL_JSON_HERE,
     "new_field_1": "field_1_value",
     "new_field_2": "field_2_value"
}
```

Where `field1,field2` does not depend on the JSON, thus the values are not relevant.

In the following demo-site (made by the original creator of the Java Jolt library):

http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception

If I do the following spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

However, when I use the same spec in NiFi JOLT processors, I get `null` as output...

How can I find the correct spec for NiFi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I wanted the output JSON to have a `data` field, but I didn't specifiy an operation to create such field. The following works:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "*": "data.&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
        "data": {},
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Please, don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.